# How does Gordon Ramsay judge each contestants' dish objectively?

Tags: reality-tv, hells-kitchen

There are heaps of competitive cooking events throughout all seasons of the American series *Hell's Kitchen* (I specify American because I believe there is a UK series I've not watched, but it's probably similar). There is usually Gordon as the judge at these events and sometimes he is supplemented by another guest chef-judge or two. Frequently he comments on the under- or over-doneness of a dish, but each judgement seems to take a few minutes. Cumulatively that would seem to position the latter contestants' dishes negatively. **How does Gordon judge each dish objectively?**

Comment: I'm not sure where the claim has been made that judging a dish, based on how much you like it, is an objective assessment.

Comment: As @AndrewMattson said, I don't think that it's a given that the dish is going to be judged objectively, especially since people watch the TV show to see him give over the top criticisms. However, a question about what the review process actually entails (since as you said, it seems to take a few minutes) would probably work as a better question.

Comment: Ramsey is a trained chef with a trained palate.  He knows how the dish should taste, and has years of experience helping him judge if the flavours/spices/etc. are unbalanced.  And while he might rant and rave, he if professional when judging, as evidenced by his other shows.

Comment: @BCdotWEB  oops, silly assumption on my part. I've edited. Thanks!

Comment: Like all television productions and movies, the material is *edited*. You may miss a lot of deliberation or back-and-forth taking more than *a few minutes*. Also, the order in which the dishes are presented may not be the same order you get to see them.

Comment: Some of the tasting is done while cooking (See [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/18750/do-contestants-receive-additional-unseen-help-as-they-progress/18788#18788)), and the judges know how long dishes take to cook. As seen on many of the time based shows, they often comment on the timing of getting things off of the heat, out of the oven, into a freezer, etc., so they have an expectation of what the taste will be based on that as well.